# How to set variables using a collection of TwoTuple in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, events

I have a main class GreenhouseControls which basically is a control system that handles various Events such as Powerout, FansOn, LightOff, ThermostatNight etc.  each of these are seperate event classes that extend a basic Event which has a delaytime and an eventTime to display all events with time interval.
GreenhouseControls has various state variables that indicate the state of an event, for example for FansOff event, "fans" variable will be false.
In my previous assignment all event classes were inner classes of GreenhouseControls and each class was setting the corresponding state varialbe.
For this assignment, I was required to make each class a separate class extends Event and Event implements Runnable, so each event will be a thread.
After we are asked to remove all state variables and replace them by a collection of TwoTuple.....the exact requirement follows:
"Remove all existing states variables in GreenhouseControls and replace them by using a collection of TwoTuple. Each time an event runs it should add an entry that identifies the variable the event is modifying as key, and another object to this structure as the value the event is setting. Create a method in GreenhouseControls called setVariable to handle updating to this collection. Use the synchronization feature in java to ensure that two Event classes are not trying to add to the structure at the same time. Again make whatever changes are required to the overall design. Provide adequate methods to access the state variables."

I did the following for this:

first, I created a basic TwoTuple class:

```
public class TwoTuple<A, B> {
    public final A variable;
    public final B value;
    public TwoTuple(A a, B b){variable = a; value = b;}
}
```

Next, in GreenhouseControls I have a collection and a setVariable method:

```
public ArrayList<TwoTuple<String,Object>> variables = new    
ArrayList<TwoTuple<String,Object>>();

public synchronized void setVariable(String variable, Object value){
variables.add(new TwoTuple<String,Object>(variable,value));
}
```

Then, in the run() method for each event I call the setVariable method with a string (which is the name of the variable as key) and a value for that key, for example LightOff.run() has the following statement:

```
gcEvent.setVariable("Light", false);  
//gcEvent is a GreenhouseControls object created in the Event 
//class to access various members of GreenhouseControls.
```

Now I am really confused about where the variables should be placed because the assignment requirement says remove all state variable.....before i had:
private boolean light = false;      //all class variables initialized to an off state

```
private boolean water = false;
private boolean fans = false;
private String thermostat = "Day";
private boolean windowok = false;
private boolean poweron = false;
```

now if I remove them then where should they be and how will they be set?
I have no clue what to do here.........can someone please take some time and help me......any comments, suggestions, answers will b greatly appreciated, I am in need for help.......PLEASE if you understand the question or know what they are asking, please reply.....Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you did for light:

```
gcEvent.setVariable("Light", false);
```

You need to do the same for your other variables:
remove:

```
private boolean water = false;
```

and do:

```
 gcEvent.setVariable("water", false);
```

Do this for all variables.